# Calculate limit without de l'Hospital rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have problem with showing that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} n (\frac{e}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}-1)=\frac{1}{2} $ without de l'Hospital rule

I thought to use the rule $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} n(\ln a-1)=a$

Comment: if Taylor series are allowed, plug in $e^{1/n}=1+1/n+1/(2n^2)+O(1/n^3)$ and $1/(1+1/n)=1-1/n+1/n^2+O(1/n^3)$

Comment: unfortunately it isn't :(

Comment: Which definition of $e$ are you using? There are several.

Comment: I think there is not limitation about def of e

Answer (score 4):

If $f(x)$ is a convex function on the interval $[a,a+1]$ then:
$$f\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)\leq\int_{a}^{a+1}f(x)\,dx\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(f(a)+f(a+1)\right),$$
hence:
$$\frac{2}{2n+1}\leq\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dt}{t}\leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\tag{1}$$
and:
$$ \frac{1}{2n+2}\leq 1-n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq\frac{1}{2n+1}\tag{2}$$
so the value of our limit is between:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} n\left(e^{\frac{1}{2n+2}}-1\right) $$
and
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} n\left(e^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}-1\right) $$
so the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$ by squeezing.